# How can i make a font using a .png image

Tags: fonts, png

I am using Font Lab Studio 5. but i dont know how to import vector file

Answer (score 7):

PNGs aren't a vector format. They are a raster format. So if you are trying to import a vector format, .png is not one. You can however use tracing tools to convert raster image formats to a vector format you can then import. Such tools are widely available; in software like Adobe Illustrator (commercial) or [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) (open-source freeware), or more directly in specialized tools like Vextractor (commercial) or [Autotrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/) (open-source freeware).

Comment: Not all fonts have to be vector. Many fonts (even in Windows) are *"bitmapped"* fonts - as opposed to TrueType or OpenType .

Answer (score 7):

## [calligraphr.com](http://www.calligraphr.com/)

1. Download a png template, which is a grid with A-Z and 0-9.
2. Paste in the letter images you have.
3. Download the ttf file.

Comment: Interesting suggestion.  Can you clarify how to paste the letter images without replacing the template?

Comment: I was looking for ways to do create a font from a png image. This was what I found. This solution requires you to paste individual letters into their template. I don't know if there are fully automated tools for this.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, submit your image to [**WhatTheFont**](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). Maybe there is already an existing font that matches the one you have on your PNG image.

Answer (score 1):

**Create your own font: my_font.ttf ||  Online and Completly free of charge**

1. Convert the files png to vector. 
   Example: **my_font_A.png** needs to be converted the into a vector New file: **my_font_A.svg**
   One possibility is using:[online-converter](http://www.online-convert.com)
2. To construct the font **my_font.ttf** it is possible to use: [Online TTF Converter](https://convertio.co/ttf-converter/). You will have to download every single letter on to the grid they will use to build the ttf file

I have done this, although I've got a problem and it is that the letters are mirrored vertically. Some kind of setting has to be set up at the online ttf converter. It can be that you have to upgrade your user account( = pay)